# How to pass variable arguments va_list from managed C++ to C#?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am developping a C++/CLI library and I have the following class:

```
public ref class AbstractClassA abstract{
  protected:
    // signature can be changed by me (method will be overriden in C#)
    virtual void write(String ^ str, String ^ format, ...array<Object^> ^args) = 0; 
  internal:
    // signature cannot be changed by me
    void internWrite(const char *str, const char *format, va_list args){
      write(gcnew String(str), gcnew String(format), ???)}
};
```

The method '*internWrite*' must call the method '*methodA*' but I am not able to find how to convert the '*va_list*' parameter to a managed array. 
I found some interesting posts [1], [2] but the mentionned solutions require to have the '*va_list*' lenght. I do not have these information and I cannot change the signature of '*internWrite*'.

I can change the signature of '*write*'.

How can I convert va_list to a managed variable args array ?

[EDIT]
The comments of the method '*internWrite*' mention:

> -format + args: formated print, same syntax as printf function

Maybe I need use the parameter '*format*' to get the length of the va_list (as mentionned on [length of va_list when using variable list arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598132/length-of-va-list-when-using-variable-list-arguments)). But how can I do that? How the printf command does that ?

[EDIT] Making the hypothesis that format+args have the same syntax as printf, I create a method to get the lenght of agrs (by countinh the '%').
Here is my code at this moment:

```
void write(char *format, va_list args){
    String^ mgFormat = gcnew String(format);
    int nbArgs = sizeOfArgs(format);
    array<Object^>^ mgArgs = gcnew array<Object^>(nbArgs);

    va_start(args, format);
    for (int _i = 0; _i < nbArgs; ++_i){
        mgArgs[_i] = va_arg(args, int); // not sure the type is int ... how to know ?
    }
    va_end(args);
    internWrite(mgFormat, mgArgs);
    }
```

But now I am stucked about adding each arg object to the array because the macro 'va_arg' requires the type of the current argument. I do not have this information. How to iterate va_list and fill my managed array?

[1] [How do I pass variable arguments from managed to unmanaged with a C++/CLI Wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821794/how-do-i-pass-variable-arguments-from-managed-to-unmanaged-with-a-c-cli-wrappe)
[2] [Calling a .NET function with variable number of parameters from unmanaged code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880553/calling-a-net-function-with-variable-number-of-parameters-from-unmanaged-code/1880851#1880851)

Comment: For managed C++/# you have to use `params` keyword: `func( params object[] arg );`.

Comment: If you have no way to get the length of the va_list, it sounds pretty hopeless.

Comment: As i see, you have a format string, which perfectly specifies the number of arguments expected once it is parsed. For a printf-like format string, you could count those '%' characters in the format string which are not preceded or succeeded immediately by another '%' char.

Comment: Géza Törötk: thank you. Since it is mentionned that it uses the printf syntax, I will count %  as you proposed.
i486: yes I will use this signature in my C# code
Medinoc: hope I will find a solution ...

Comment: Unless you know the format string is constrained to 32-bit types, you can't assume each argument is in fact an `int` or at least the same size. You will have to not only count the `%` characters, but also look at the format character following it and adjust the size of each `va_arg` accordingly. But I don't understand the code example. You show both `write` calling `internWrite` and `internWrite` calling `write`, which is an infinite loop! You should make a code example that shows clearly the exact relationship between caller and callee, including code that uses this class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to parse the format argument, in order to determine both the number of arguments and the type of the arguments. The va_list doesn't contain the type information, it seems like.

A suggestion, if you really want to go down that road, is to read the [vsnprintf](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/libs/klibc/klibc.git/tree/usr/klibc/vsnprintf.c) documentation, but it seems like some work lies ahead of you!

Even